# MySQL cursor when used with SQLEXCEPTION handler is skipping processing the row next to the problematic row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that iterates through the information schema tables using a cursor, and for each table, it checks for a condition and proceeds with additional logic execution

In my case, the stored procedure ran into an error, as the variable holding the cursor values has precision 30, while one of the tables has precision greater than 30.

This is causing an error in the fetch statement.

To handle this error, and any other potential cursor fetch errors, I am adding an SQLEXCEPTION handler.

The expectation is that, when problematic table runs in error at fetch, it is logged and cursor continuous with the next row.

But in my case, the cursor is moving to the next to next of problematic row - effectively skipping a table. I confirmed this by printing debug statements. This doesn't happen if the error occurs elsewhere other than in Fetch statement.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE call_proc_X()
   LANGUAGE SQL
   NOT DETERMINISTIC
   SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  DECLARE Finished BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE TableName VARCHAR(30);
  DECLARE TablesCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'myschema';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Finished = TRUE;

  OPEN TablesCursor;

  MainLoop: LOOP
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR: ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
            INSERT INTO error_log(message,run_at) VALUES (@full_error ,NOW());
        END;
      FETCH TablesCursor INTO TableName;
      IF Finished THEN
          LEAVE MainLoop;
      END IF;

      IF TableName <> 'error_log' THEN
          -- CALL proc_X('myschema',TableName);
      END IF;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END
```